# Which cooking device allows flexible temperature programming?

Tags: oven, milk

A typical electric oven seems both an overkill and insufficient to make baked milk or a home made diary product like joghurt or matzoon.

- overkill: too big, energy consumption, might be needed for many other things if blocked for ours
- insufficient: rarely can be set to support say 25°C to sustain bacterial life, mine anyway not.

Do you have an idea how is a better suited, [autoclave](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoclave) like, cooking device actually device called?!

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baked_milk

P.S. for diary products only, I didn't know there are indeed autoclave-like kitchen joghurt makers, they mostly support fixed temperatures, but typically not beyond 45°C. For baked milk, you need 70°C.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily (and very accurately) do this with an immersion circulator, such as [Joule](https://www.breville.com/us/en/products/sous-vide.html) or [Anova](https://anovaculinary.com/).  In fact, your application is an excellent one for what has become known as cooking "sous vide."

Comment: thanks - though I'd need to put milk in a plastic bag?

Comment: You can use jars, such as canning jars.  I make yogurt this way regularly.

Comment: ok just to understand the terminology and the process, you use the sous vise device immersed into jar but the cooking is actually not - formally seen - sous vide? (which is fine to me)

Comment: See: https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/easy-delicious-sous-vide-yogurt